# Passing artifactId to surefire argLine

Tags: maven, profiling, maven-surefire-plugin, async-profiler

I'm trying to use [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) with maven, sadly it does not track forked processes and my tests need the isolation provided by forks to run correctly.

In order to run async-profiler I need to run java with this parameter:

```
-agentpath:/path/to/libasyncProfiler.so=start,svg,file=profile.svg
```

I was thinking using [surefire's `argLine`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine), but it would erase `profile.svg` each time.
I was thinking using the project's `artifactId` do parameterized it, but I found no reference on that.

How can get the artifactId on the tested project in the `argLine` field?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Introduction to the POM, Project Model Variables](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Model_Variables):

> Any field of the model that is a single value element can be referenced as a variable.

For your case it's `${project.artifactId}`. Use this in Surefire configuration's `<argLine>`.